# What is the most efficient way to use the importrange formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, performance, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I built a quasi-relational database out of several Google spreadsheets (Forms feed these spreadsheets) and I `importrange` from several sheets into a "master".
In one place I `importrange` the entire sheet into the master spreadsheet, then `query` or `vlookup` in that local sheet to find the values I need. In another place I `query(importrange)` each cell in a column to pull the values I need. Here is an example formula I am using per cell:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id","'Form Responses 1'!A2:H"),"Select Col8 where Col4 ="&J2&" Limit 1")
```

Do you have an opinion of which of these is more efficient? This system is, at times, fairly slow. Now that it works, I would like to fine-tune it and make it more efficient.

I am also considering feeding all the forms into the master, which I know would be faster, but have had issues in the past with feeding multiple forms into a single spreadsheet. Has anyone else had issues with feeding 4 or 5 forms into the same spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

more importranges you have the slower is the overall performance. the most efficient way is to import all of your data into your sheet with `IMPORTRANGE` formula and then refer to those data instead of having another formula to refer to the other spreadsheet.